# Use Django header to pass data

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and now facing a problem.

I don't know how to pass a data from one webpage to another using html header. (using Django)

Usually I use django form with post method to pass the data
But now I need to pass the data without form.

Here's what I want to do:

- json.py handles a webpage that produces json data
- chart.py handles a webpage that receives json data and turn it into charts

I need the json data to save in somewhere and post it to the webpage that chart.py controls

I've read the docs but I have poor understanding to it.

To be short, I want to ask 2 things:

1. How to save the data in json.py and post to chart.py? (through header)
2. After post, how to get the data from header? (in chart.py)

Comment: What do you mean by header? and what benefit will you get using ONLY header?

Comment: The header here is refered to HTTP header.
I'm just trying some other ways to pass data rather than sessions or form post

Comment: Then  why can't you pull json data using ajax request?

Comment: That's a good approach, but I am just trying to test if this works.

Comment: Your approach is not compatible with django's philosophy, Instead use angularjs like framework to go to another page with some data from another page.

Comment: OK then, thanks for the help.

Comment: Do let us know what you go with

Comment: you mean the answer accepted?

Comment: No. The approach you go with, to solve this specific problem.

Comment: I think i will use session then.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you mean by "header" here but it seems unlikely to be what you want. If you need to pass data from one view to another, the best way is to use the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#examples).

Comment: The header here is refered to HTTP header.

From what I read in the docs online

It says like:
 
  payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}

  r = requests.post("http://httpbin.org/post", data=payload)

Comment: But ... what? What? You're not doing anything with a header in that code at all.

Comment: Yeah I know, but is there a way to do something simliar like that?
Save data into post method and pass it to other webpage?

Comment: No. Why would you want to do that? *That is what the session is for*.

Comment: OK I see. But there's no any way to save data in post/get request?

Comment: Look, you seem to have some kind of category error here and it's impossible to tell what you're asking. If you want to send post data, then do that; you've already given the code for doing so. But I don't understand what that has to do with headers.